# Django raising 'django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '/' not found. '/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.' in base.html

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls

I am making a website using Django and DTL. I wanted to comment the embedded javascript in my code, but it happens that *Django Template Language* ***does not*** comment the same way as plain HTML.

Traceback when I go to ***any*** page:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for '/' not found. '/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for '/' not found. '/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/william/Documents/coding/WDTP/almostanything/django/almostanything',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/william/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 17 Feb 2021 09:43:34 -0500
Error during template rendering
In template /Users/william/Documents/coding/WDTP/almostanything/django/almostanything/templates/base.html, error at line 20
```

Main issue:

***Reverse for '/' not found. '/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.***

```
1   {% load static %}
2   <!DOCTYPE html>
3   <html lang="en">
4   <head>
5       <meta charset="UTF-8">
6       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
7       {% block title %}<title>Home</title>{% endblock %}
8       {% block style %}<style>
9           /* div#shadowtopbar{
10              display: none;

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 179, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/Users/william/Documents/coding/WDTP/almostanything/django/almostanything/home/views.py, line 5, in home_unlogged
    return render(request, 'home_unlogged.html') …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py, line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py, line 61, in render
            return self.template.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 170, in render
                    return self._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 162, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 150, in render
            return compiled_parent._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 162, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 62, in render
                result = block.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 446, in render
            url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/base.py, line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)) …
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
        raise NoReverseMatch(msg) …
▶ Local vars
```

HTML code (base.html in almostanything/templates/):

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% block title %}<title>Home</title>{% endblock %}
    {% block style %}<style>
        /* div#shadowtopbar{
            display: none;
        }
        /* tr's 
        .tr1{top:4px;right:4px;}.tr2{top:4px;right:39px;}.tr3{top:4px;right:79px;}
        .shadowed{box-shadow:3px 3px 1px 0px blue;} */
    </style>{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block script %}
    <script>
        #     var st = document.getElementById('shadowtopbar'); 
        #     function load(); 
        #         st.style.display = "block"; 
        #     setTimeout(500, load()); 
    </script> 
    {% endblock %}
    {% block topbar %}
    <div id="shadowtopbar">
        <a href="{% url '/' %}" rel="noopener noreferrer"><button><img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}"></button></a>
        <!-- <a class="tr1 shadowed" href="{% url '/' %}" rel="noopener noreferrer"><button>Login</button></a>
        <a class="tr2 shadowed" href="{% url '/' %}" rel="noopener noreferrer"><button>Signup</button></a> -->
        <a class="tr3 shadowed" href="{% url '/' %}" rel="noopener noreferrer"><button>About Us</button></a>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The argument inside a `{% url %}` tag is supposed to be the name of a view, not an actual url path.

Comment: If you really do want a url path, don't use `{% url %}`.  Just use `<a href="/">`

Comment: @JohnGordon It's bas.html _**line 20**_.

Comment: Huh?  As far as I can see, line 20 is the first line in the `<script>` tag...

Comment: @JohnGordon it _is_ line 20, the browser is marking the `t.getElementB`.

Comment: @JohnGordon after I edited the post, the browser was not marking anywhere